# keep user info cached across app

Tags: angularjs

i have an angularjs app with a non-angular login page. so after logging in you're redirected to the angular app. i've set up an $httpProvider so that any request that is made that results in a 401 will redirect the user back to the login page.

in the meantime while the user is in the app i'd like to have user detail info available to the app at all times. like username, some settings, etc. ideally i'd have this information available before the initial view loads. and ideally i'd only grab this information once.

what's the best way to do that? i could use a service to cache the user between controllers/views but how can i prime it so that it has the necessary information before the initial view is shown to the user (since some data is necessary to display that initial view)?

Comment: So you are saying that if you refresh a page you will be redirected to the login page even if logged in?

Comment: no - the server renders the app for all logged in users. so if you refresh and you are still logged in you will remain on the app. but if your session expires and then you refresh you will be redirected to the login page *by the server* (whereas requests that return a 401 will redirect to the login page *by the client*)

Comment: You could simply use a service/factory. The service would perform an Ajax request to fetch the data and then store it. Services are singletons so data should be available between controllers. It also means that the Ajax request will only occur once.

Comment: @WayneEllery but how can i ensure that it's loaded before the first view is displayed? (i'm new to angular so maybe the answer is obviously part of your last response but not obvious to me!)

Comment: I have to think about that now. That is the crux of the question

Comment: @WayneEllery i suppose one option is to include a `<div ng-show="!user">spinner</div><div ng-show="!!user">actual view</div>` but yuk

Comment: Yeah. That's what I was going to suggest. I've used [angular-spinner](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner) to do it in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using ngRoute or uiRouter? Take advantage of its `resolve` feature which lets you resolve promises before route change / state change occurs. Use a service, as suggested above. Give it a method which resolves a promise once you've checked whether you're logged in.

After the response arrives, resolve the promise. Then Angular will instantiate the controller and make the route transition, and you can inject the service again and render your page knowing that the content is ready.

Answer (score 0):

When successful login happens you can have the user details saved in local storage. you could then retrieve the information anywhere in angular space by injecting $localstorage into your code